# How to place footer above keyboard (Ionic 3)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to place my footer directly above keypad at the bottom.

HTML:

```
<ion-footer >
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons>
    <button ion-button (click) = getBlurred() >
      button1
    </button>
    <button ion-button >
      button2
    </button>
    <button ion-button >
      button3
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
  {{focusedElement ? focusedElement.value : "null"}}
</ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom : 0;
}
```

The fixed property allowed me to place the footer at the bottom. 
However, each time i activate the input field, the position changes differently. How can i solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ?

Comment: @Scobee
platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml and change the rule windowSoftInputMode:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`

And every time the footer is created, i adjusted margin.